# How to display Recent activity item in ionic application

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to display all the recent activity on a new screen in ionic application, but i am not able to get the logic how to display all the recent activity item on a screen, say if i have played video and seen pdf then it should reflect in the recent Activity item, Please suggest, Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create counter for each activity counter will be increases when any activity is done and then you can reflect that counter

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.